# How to force the user to fill forms before doing something else?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I would like to know how to force the user to fill forms before doing something else. I have a private area. I need the user to fill 4 forms. It's a job's board.

I want to fill the forms with wizardforms. How can I force the user to do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear if you don't like the answer below. Please be clearer on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [nice tutorial](http://superjared.com/entry/formwizard-multiple-step-forms-django/) that shows you how to use `FormWizard`. And of course there is the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).

Comment: yeah, i have that tutorial in my bookmarks, but im dont know , how force the user to fill after all?